# Connecting to a computer on a switch from a computer directory from router

Tags: networking, router, switch

So I have 3 Computers:

```
Computer 1: Connected Directly to router. Vendor: Cisco, Model: DPC3939
Computer 2: Connected to switch. Vendor Dynex, Model:: DX-E401
Computer 3: Connected to switch. Vendor Dynex, Model:: DX-E401
```

Computer 2 & 3 can ping each other and connect to the internet.

Computer 1 can connect to the internet and can ping the switch.

The problem is I need computer one to be able to talk to the computers on the switch.

Computer 1:
[image]
Computer 2:
[image]
Computer 3:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your switch isn't a switch, [it's a router](http://www.dynexproducts.com/products/computer-accessories/DX-E401.html), with its own DHCP server.

Look closely at the IPv4 adresses of your PCs 2 & 3. They're in the 192.168.x.x range. PC 1 has an IP of 10.x.x.x. This tells me they are getting their IP's from different sources.

Disable the DHCP server in your Dynex router, connect all PCs and the Cisco router to LAN ports on the Dynex and you *shoud* be good to go.

Thanks to the link provided by Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, the manual can be found [here](http://www.dynexproducts.com/cms/documents/Manuals/DX-E401_Manual.pdf), page 21 explains how the configure your DHCP server in the Dynex router.

Comment: It's for sure a consumer DSL/Cable router: [Dynex DX-E401](http://www.dynexproducts.com/products/computer-accessories/DX-E401.html)

Comment: Laziness on my part, I know, but I didn't google the Dynex device.

Comment: Thanks, that partially helped, but I don't want computer once connected to the switch.

Comment: Although you seem to have it working, just for clarification (in case anyone else reads this), your wiring was correct, it was just the DHCP server in your Dynex router that had to be disabled.